# Optimal way to collect keys into an Array JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization

What is the optimal way to get unique strings in an array? There are times when it makes sense to do it one of many ways, here are 3:

1. creating an array and, for each new item you push, first check if `_.indexOf(array, newItem) == -1`
2. creating a hash, with all values as `true`, such as `{key1: true, key2: true}`, then `_.keys(hash)`
3. pushing all items in the array, then running `keys = _.uniq(keys)`

The above code is using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) helpers.

Having knowledge of the internals of JavaScript constructs/vm's, and some formal algorithms knowledge, would probably make this a no brainer but I'm not there yet. I'm sure it differs from browser to browser (and node), but maybe there is a preferred approach. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first solution has to loop through every element of the array, for each element of the array. That makes a complexity of `O(n²)`.

The second is probably the best, because it only loops through the array, then loops through the keys. That's basically `O(2n)`, which is just `O(n)`.

The third depends on how efficient `uniq()` is. For instance, it might well just be an implementation of method 2.

Comment: At small scales (less than 50 keys per object), the first solution seems to be more than 3x as fast as the second in node: https://gist.github.com/4633028.